# Google sheet chart, wrong time format in chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have created a Google Sheet that collects a bunch of values in columns. One of these is a time value formatted `hh:mm:ss AM/PM`, obtained with the following formula:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE("April 28, 2019 at 02:03PM"," at ", " "))
```

However, these values are shown incorrectly in the chart:

[image]

Apparently, I can't find a way to customise time format in the chart... How should I fix this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- tick the **Treat labels as text** checkbox:

[image: 0]

Comment: The chart will shrink and only two labels will be shown: https://ibb.co/x8nHN5G

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w_3MZFeI5AwnVj6eAUDfIdk8ymz0OaN5LmXREaPtUyk/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @Riccardo https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JkFt.png